# What's the difference between the components ReactMapGL and MapGL in the react-map-gl library?

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

I can't understand the difference between the component ReactMapGL and the component MapGL in the react-map-gl library. The docs don't explain it and they seem to have the same properties.

https://uber.github.io/react-map-gl/#/Documentation/getting-started/adding-custom-data even the examples use them intermittently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference, they (`ReactMapGl` and `MapGL`) are just plain names for exported by default `InteractiveMap` component.

Even according to the sources of react-map-gl:
[image]